# Chemical potential of ideal solution in grand canonical ensemble

Tags: statistical-mechanics, partition-function, chemical-potential

I am attempting to derive the chemical potential of an ideal solution within the grand canonical ensemble. I know that the final answer should be (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_solution)
$$\mu_j=\mu_j^0+kT\ln q_j,$$
where $q_j$ is the fraction of molecules of type $j$ in the solution. As shown below, I can derive the correct functional form but with a specific choice of $\mu_j^0=kT$. I wonder how to modify this derivation to get the general $\mu_j^0$. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

*Derivation*

Consider a heat bath of $N$ independent molecules, each of which can be of type $j$. Let there be $y_j$ molecules of type $j$. Then, $q_j=y_j/N$ is the fraction of molecules of type $j$ and also the probability that a randomly chosen molecule in the solution belongs to the component $j$. Therefore, the entropy of the heat bath is

$$S_{bath}=-k\sum_{\textrm{N molecules}}\sum_jq_j\ln q_j=-kN\sum_jq_j\ln q_j=-k\sum_j y_j\ln\frac{y_j}{N}.$$

Now, imagine a focal system with a variable number of molecules $n_j$ of type $j$ that is connected to the heat bath and can exchange molecules with the heat bath. We assign chemical potentials $\mu_j$ to molecules of type $j$. The grand partition function of the focal system is
$$\mathcal{Z}=\sum_{\{n_j\}}e^{-(E-\sum_j\mu_jn_j)/kT}$$
and the entropy is
$$S_{focal}=k\frac{\partial}{\partial T}(T\ln\mathcal{Z})=\ln \mathcal{Z}+\frac{1}{T}\langle E \rangle - \sum_j\frac{\mu_j}{T}\langle n_j \rangle.$$

Therefore,
$$\frac{\mu_j}{T}=-\frac{\partial S_{focal}}{\partial \langle n_j \rangle}.$$

At thermodynamic equilibrium, the change in entropy in one system is reflected by a change in entropy in the other system, so
$$\frac{\partial S_{focal}}{\partial \langle n_j \rangle}=\frac{\partial S_{bath}}{\partial y_j}=-k \ln \frac{y_j}{N}-k=-k \ln q_j-k.$$

Putting things together,
$$\mu_j=-T\frac{\partial S_{focal}}{\partial \langle n_j \rangle}=kT\ln q_j+kT.$$